# AVRoutePickerView not changing color when AirPlay video

Tags: swift, avkit

I have a custom video player. Im using AVRoutePickerView to enable AirPlay. It works fine and it's playing on my Apple TV.
But the AVRoutePickerView is not changing color / animating when AirPlay is active.
This only applies when AirPlay to an Apple TV / TV. When AirPods is selected it works fine, and the icon is animating.

Anyone know what could cause this problem?

This is my config of AVRoutePickerView:

```
   private func setupRoutePicker() {
    if let controlsOverlayView = controlsOverlayView {
        routerPickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: controlsOverlayView.airPlayButtonContainer.frame)
        controlsOverlayView.airPlayButtonContainer.addSubview(routerPickerView)
        routerPickerView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        routerPickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        routerPickerView.tintColor = settings.airPlayIconTintColor
        routerPickerView.activeTintColor = settings.airPlayIconActivTintColor
        routerPickerView.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            routerPickerView.prioritizesVideoDevices = true
        }
    }
}
```